# WCF - Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'getWorkOrderStatus'. OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message

Tags: asp.net, wcf, soap

I receive the following error when I try to get a work order status through WCF API call:

Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'getWorkOrderStatus'. OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'getWorkOrderStatusResponse' and namespace ''. Found node type 'Element' with name 'SOAP-ENV:getWorkOrderStatusResponse' and namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'

This is a new .Net Core project (4.6.1.). I have created the proxy classes using  srvcutil 4.6.1 from https://www.fieldnation.com/api/v3.3/fieldnation.wsdl. I had to comment out some of the attributes that were auto generated since .net core doesn't seem to have them. It is most likely one of these causing the issue but I don't know what is the workaround.

This is the actual response I get back using SOAP UI:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <SOAP-ENV:getWorkOrderStatusResponse>
     <return xsi:type="xsd:string">Assigned</return>
  </SOAP-ENV:getWorkOrderStatusResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here is anything I could find that seemed relevant in the generated code:

```
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
//[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="getWorkOrderStatusResponse", WrapperNamespace="", IsWrapped=true)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "SOAP-ENV:getWorkOrderStatusResponse", WrapperNamespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsWrapped = true)]
public partial class getWorkOrderStatusResponse
{

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="", Order=0)]
    public string @return;

    public getWorkOrderStatusResponse()
    {
    }

    public getWorkOrderStatusResponse(string @return)
    {
        this.@return = @return;
    }
}
```

Comment: First things first, is that second block of code multiple pieces of code you got from different places ? Also, the error comes from this attribute most likely: `[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "getWorkOrderStatusResponse", WrapperNamespace = "", IsWrapped = true)]`. It should be `[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "SOAP-ENV:getWorkOrderStatusResponse", WrapperNamespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsWrapped = true)]`

Comment: Yes. I copied and pasted from the svcutil generated code the pieces that had workorderstatus in them. After changing the attribute you suggested the error changed to:

Comment: Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'SOAP-ENV_x003A_getWorkOrderStatusResponse' and namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'. Found node type 'Element' with name 'SOAP-ENV:getWorkOrderStatusResponse' and namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'

Comment: I suggest you either separate the bits of code (using the _edit_ function) or simply post one of them, since it's fairly hard to read right now. As for the error, the namespace seems to be right; can't you change the `WrapperName` to `SOAP-ENV_x003A_getWorkOrderStatusResponse` ?

Comment: I think you are on the right track just the colon is getting encoded for some reason. I removed the rest of the code for clarity. Pasting SOAP-ENV_x003A_getWorkOrderStatusResponse did not work. My concern is that this code was generated with svcutil. If this one is wrong than I am going to have trouble with the rest of the code. Is there an alternative generating the code? I tried the visual studio WCF connected service extension but it chokes on the the same attributes as svcutil. Is the WSDL wrong?

Comment: I don't know those enough to suggest any alternatives, hence the comments and no answer. I hope this helped a bit anyway. Also, you have no return type in `public getWorkOrderStatusResponse(string @return)`